# How to Access Secret Key Hash and PKH from a web wallet?

Tags: wallet, nami-wallet, public-key, signing-key-file, lightwallet

So I'm making a Dapp that uses the user's secret key to encrypt the data. It also allows another user to encrypt something else using their public key hash, but how do I get the key pairs from the web wallet integrated with my Dapp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly access private keys of your users; those should reside safely in their wallet only.

There is, however, a way you can have their wallet use those keys to sign data that you pass over.

This is described in CIP 30: https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip30/#apisigndataaddraddresspayloadbytespromisedatasignature

You call this function in the browser like so:

```
window.cardano.signData(Address, HexMsgToSign)
```

The wallet will then open a window showing the message and asking the user to sign, and return the signature.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the secret/private key of a wallet connected to your web site.